# using extern keyword to declare variables in header files / c++

Tags: c++, header

What is the proper way of declaring variables in the header file in c++? And if it is not a good idea, then why? Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the proper way"? If you need a declaration for a variable in a header file then you just put a declaration in a header file. The fact that you want to put it in a header file doesn't make a difference to the syntax that you should use.

Comment: i have been told that i should use `extern`. whats is the reason for doing so?

Comment: to be honest im a little confused. i have never heard about extern before.

Comment: @Abdulai: In some contexts adding adding `extern` can prevent a declaration from also being a definition but it has the same effect on declarations in header files as other source files. If you want to ask what `extern` is used for then make _that_ your question; it would be less cryptic.

Comment: the extern keyword says to the compiler: Don't allocate memory for this variable, you will find it in another file. So you need one cpp file where the variable is declared without the extern keyword and all other files accessing it have to declare it with extern.

Comment: @Heinzi: No it doesn't mean that. E.g. `extern int k = 21;` is a perfectly good declaration *and* definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way would be to declare the variable with the extern keyword in the header file and then you have to declare it in one (!) cpp file without the extern keyword.

**But:**

Variables in header files are global variables. These have much problems. Here a few:

- You don't know in which order they are initialized. When one is a class and their constructor accesses another global variable, it is possible that this other global variable isn't initialized
- Global variables waste your namespace
- When you use global variables, you almost certainly don't use well-known and proven programming concepts (like modularity). Also your functions will have many side effects which makes your code hard to understand. In a few weeks you will no longer know, which functions will change which variables, and so on. Your code will be much more readable and understandable, if you stick to this concepts and don't use global variables.

You should never use global variables in C++. They are only there for backward compatibility with C.

Comment: "and then you have to declare it in one (!) cpp file" --> should it be a cpp file that comes with the header file and defines classes and functions declared in it? or it doesnt matter?

Comment: You seem to be bordering on the implication that global variables are more acceptable in C than C++. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @Abdulali: It doesn't matter, as long as they are equally named and have the equal type. But again: Don't use them - they are only a leftover from C.

Comment: @Charles: Many arguments used for C++ also make using global variables in C code unpleasant. But in C code there sometimes are circumstances where you can't avoid them, because you don't have singletons or static class members.

Comment: These are all problems with global variables in C as well.

Comment: I don't understand how not having singletons (surely a good thing!) and not having static class members (static _data_ members, I presume) necessarily that you need to use global variables (by which I mean objects with external linkage) more in C.

Comment: Whereever you can avoid them, this is great. Since I switched from C to C++ I didn't use global variables. But I do remember that there were some use cases in my C times where I needed them. But it is possible that now - with my current experience - I would find ways to avoid them even in C.